# Count element until offset

Tags: jquery, html

I have some codes like that :

```
<div id="content">
<span class="pivot">1</span>
Some pure text here
<span class="pivot">2</span>
Some pure text here
<span class="pivot">3</span>
Some pure text here
<span class="pivot">4</span>
TEXT FOR SELECTION
<span class="pivot">5</span>
Some pure text here
</div>
```

My problem:

- I select the text "TEXT FOR SELECTION" by mouse
- **I want count how many span of class PIVOT before the TEXT FOR SELECTION**

Somebody can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to modify your HTML like this :

```
<div id="content" onmouseup="selectText()">
<span class="pivot">1</span>
Some pure text here
<span class="pivot">2</span>
Some pure text here
<span class="pivot">3</span>
Some pure text here
<span class="pivot">4</span>
TEXT FOR SELECTION
<span class="pivot">5</span>
Some pure text here
</div>
```

and you need to write script:

```
function selectText(element) {
        if (window.getSelection) {
            var selection = window.getSelection();  
            if(selection.extentNode.data.trim() == "TEXT FOR SELECTION"){
                var counter = 0;
                var a = $('#content')[0].childNodes;
                for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++){                
                    var check=a[i];
                    if(check.data != undefined && check.data.trim() == "TEXT FOR SELECTION"){
                        break;
                    }
                    if(check.data == undefined)
                        counter++;
                }
                alert(counter);
            }        
        }
    }
```

You will get number of span tags in alert.

Comment: Well, that's really nice. But if i select text somewhere else, not TEXT FOR SELECTION, how can i do?

Answer (score 0):

Each element, text or span, is a childNode. So if you get the index of the childNode you select and subtract 1 you get your answer. However I am not sure if is there a way to catch if mouse enters childNode.

So I think it is better you surround all your elements with span, then add `onMouseOver="getIndex(this)"` for getting the index of the child.

```
function getIndex(child){
    var children = document.getElementById("content").children;

    for(i = 0; i < children.length; i++)
        if(child == children[i])
        alert("Element number " + i)
}
```

and content would be like;

```
<div id="content">
    <span class="pivot" onmouseover="getIndex(this)">1</span>
    <span onmouseover="getIndex(this)">Some pure text here</span>
    <span class="pivot" onmouseover="getIndex(this)">2</span>
    <span onmouseover="getIndex(this)">Some pure text here</span>
    <span class="pivot" onmouseover="getIndex(this)">3</span>
    <span onmouseover="getIndex(this)">Some pure text here</span>
    <span class="pivot" onmouseover="getIndex(this)">4</span>
    <span onmouseover="getIndex(this)">TEXT FOR SELECTION</span>
    <span class="pivot" onmouseover="getIndex(this)">5</span>
    <span onmouseover="getIndex(this)">Some pure text here</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Opps, i dont want to wrap it by span tag. I just want to determine how many span before the text i've selected.